# routing with parameters not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Having issue while routing

common.js

```
when('/showmessage/:groupkey/:groupmessage', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/groups/showmessage.html',
    controller: 'GroupsController'
  }).
 when('/showmessage/:groupkey/:channelmessage', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/channels/showmessage.html',
    controller: 'ChannelsController'
  }).
```

index.html

```
<md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="usergroup in usergroups">
<a ng-href="#/showmessage/{{usergroupkey}}/{{'groupmessage'}}">
    <img ng-src="images/abc.png" class="md-avatar">                 
</a> 
<a ng-href="#/showmessage/{{usergroupkey}}/{{'channelmessage'}}">
    <img ng-src="images/abc.png" class="md-avatar">                 
</a>
```

When I click on group(1st link) it outputs grouplist page.
But, when I click on channel(2nd link) it outputs grouplist page.
Issue is when I am using different controllers, urls then why it is displaying same list page.

Comment: Angular's ng-router takes URL's into consideration, so in this you don't have 2 different URLs, even though param names are different. I'd suggest you to change URL or use ui-router for routing. Something like `showgroupmessage` and `showchannelmessage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete Antenka answer here is how you should write things :

```
when('/showmessage/groupmessage/:groupkey', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/groups/showmessage.html',
    controller: 'GroupsController'
  }).
when('/showmessage/channelmessage/:groupkey', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/channels/showmessage.html',
    controller: 'ChannelsController'
}).
```

Usage :

```
<md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="usergroup in usergroups">
<a ng-href="#/showmessage/groupmessage/{{usergroupkey}}">
    <img ng-src="images/abc.png" class="md-avatar">                 
</a> 
<a ng-href="#/showmessage/channelmessage/{{usergroupkey}}">
    <img ng-src="images/abc.png" class="md-avatar">                 
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your query matched at the 1st route, so it won't proceed to the next one. Giving different names to the params, doesn't give you different URLs.